# Xcode TableViewCell is reusing content upon button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I realize this is a common problem but I'm just not getting it. I have a button that when pressed on a cell, changes to a check mark. However, when pressed it changes other reused cell's image to a check mark as well. I'm using a cell's delegate to manipulate local data on the tableView's VC.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Configure the cell...
    static NSString *ReusableIdentifier = @"Cell";
     SetListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ReusableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.delegate = self;

    if ([self.selectedRows containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
    [cell.plusButton setBackgroundImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            [cell.plusButton setBackgroundImage:plusImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
cell.tag = indexPath.Row

    return cell; 

    }
```

Method in custom cell's class.

```
- (IBAction)addSongButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
[self.delegate addSongButtonPressedOnCell:self];

UIImage *checkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
[self.plusButton setBackgroundImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Method from the cell's delegate.

```
-(void)addSongButtonPressedOnCell:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger index =  ((UIButton *)sender).tag;

NSMutableDictionary *track = [self.searchTracks objectAtIndex:indexPath];

[self.selectedRows addIndex:indexPath];


}
```

Comment: Subclass your cells and look into `prepareForReuse`

Comment: Are you using any table cell insertions / deletions? I'd check to make sure your index tag is always correct - if the cell order ever changes without calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` your cell's index will be incorrect.

Comment: I am not. Logging my button click, the index is always right.@Jpoliachik